# Julia : the size of h5 file

Tags: file, julia

I stored a matrix of 10000*5000 in h5 file that has values of 1 and -1.

```
h5open("/my path/data.h5", "w") do file
    write(file, "a", a)  # alternatively, say "@write file A"
```

It took 400 MB. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Did you try storing a matrix of 10000*5000 booleans (i.e. `rand(Bool,10000,5000)`)? It would be nice if you reported this size

Comment: bool , why ? but l need real values !!

Comment: Ah, OK. you said 1 and -1 and I thought you could easily store this in a bool matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely what you should expect, provided that these are `Float64` numbers being stored.  Each `Float64` number takes up 64 bits = 8 Bytes.  10000*5000*8 = 400 million bytes = 400 MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut down on size, you could also consider generating and storing the values as another type such as `Int8` (which will take 1/8th the space of `Float64`).  Keep in mind though that if you add, multiply, etc. anything in your matrix times another type of object, then Julia will automatically convert the types to match.  Such conversions will result in a big performance penalty if you perform such operations multiple times, thus resulting in multiple conversions.  But, you could still store it as such and then reconvert it after loading.